# Why does Codeigniter4 Query Builder not work with model in controller?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I've written just like- $this->userModel->where('email', $email)->findAll() code in my codeigniter Controller. But it's not retrieving any result as var_dump got me array(0), as well showing no error too. But $email is ok. What can I do now? Thank you.

Here is my Code...

```
public function login() {
        if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'):
            $email = $this->request->getVar('email');
            $data = $this->userModel->where('email', $email)->findAll();
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($data); die;
            $rules = $this->userModel->getValidationRules(['only' => ['email', 'password']]);
            if(!$this->validate($rules)):
                $this->session->setFlashdata('errors', $this->validator->getErrors());
                return redirect()->back()->withInput();
            else:
                $data = $this->request->getPost();
                $user = $this->userModel->where('email', $data['email'])->first();
                $varify = password_verify($data['password'], $user['password']);
                if($varify == true):
                    $this->session->set('user', $user); 
                    $this->session->setFlashdata('success', 'You are loged in sussessfully. Thank you.');
                    return redirect()->to('/');
                else:
                    $this->session->setFlashdata('error', 'Unknown Email/Password. Please try with correct one. Thank you.');
                    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
                endif;
            endif;
        endif;
    }
```

And, Here is my model code:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UserModel extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $returnType = 'array';
    protected $allowedFields = ['user', 'name', 'email', 'phone', 'gender', 'password', 'address', 'city', 'estate', 'country', 'image'];
    // protected $beforeInsert = ['hashPassword'];
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;
    protected $useTimestamps = false;
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';
    protected $validationRules = [
        'user'              => [
                'label'         => 'User ID',
                'rules'         => 'trim|required|is_unique[users.user,id,{id}]|alpha_numeric|min_length[3]'
        ],
        'gender'            => [
            'label'             => 'Gender',
            'rules'             => 'trim|required'
        ],
        'email'             => [
            'label'             => 'E-mail ID',
            'rules'             => 'trim|required|is_unique[users.email,id,{id}]|valid_email'
        ],
        'password'          => [
            'label'             => 'Password',
            'rules'             => 'trim|required|min_length[5]'
        ],
        'confirm_password'  => [
            'label'             => "Password Confirmation",
            'rules'             => 'trim|required|matches[password]'
        ],
        'phone'             => [
            'label'             => 'Phone Number',
            'rules'             => 'trim|numeric|max_length[13]|is_unique[users.phone,id,{id}]'
        ],
        'address'           => [
            'label'             => 'Address',
            'rules'             => 'trim|alpha_numeric_space'
        ],
        'city'              => [
            'label'             => 'City',
            'rules'             => 'trim|alpha_numeric_space'
        ],
        'estate'            => [
            'label'             => 'Estate',
            'rules'             => 'trim|alpha_space'
        ],
        'country'           => [
            'label'             => 'Country',
            'rules'             => 'trim|alpha_space'
        ]
    ];
    protected $validationMessages = [];
    protected $skipValidation     = false;

    public function hashPassword($data) {
        if(! isset($data['password'])) return $data;
        $data['password'] = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        return $data;
    }

    public function insertData($data) {
        $user = $this->hashPassword($data);
        if($this->db->table('users')->insert($user)):
            return true;
        endif;
    }
}
```

Please, help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your userModel code too here ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mr. @Dhaval Chheda for responding to my question. Here, I've amended my post with model code, as per your instruction. Please, go through the post again. Thank you again. :)

Comment: Your Model seems fine. Do you have entry in your db ?

Comment: Yes @Dhaval Chheda. I have.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Can you also post the code where you have declared $this->userModel? I can't find any issue with the code that you have presented here. Try  $data = $this->userModel->findAll() and see if the data is printed or not.

Comment: @Dhaval Chheda, I've posted it in the controller constructor, like-                       
class UserController extends BaseController
{
    protected $userModel;
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userModel = new UserModel();
    }